# SQL and new runtime tables

Tags: mysql

I'm designing a database for a website that has to be dynamically modified.

I'll be clearer: there are registered users, who have to complete some  surveys (that have to be saved on the same DB). The admin can create and submit to users new surveys. The admin could want to submit a survey just to users who are older than 50yo.

The problem is that I can't find a DB design to solve this problem. All of my ideas are realizable with graph DB, but not with relational DB.

Can you help me to find the right way?

Here is the schema:

```
    member(id, email, password, salt) 
    member_details(name, surname, region, province, age, job, education)
```

Now, if the admin wants to submit a new survey to all users, I create (through PHP code) a new table, Survey1:

```
    Survey1(uid, answer1, answer2, ..., answer10)
```

And it is not so hard. The problem is if she wants to submit a survey just to users over 50yo. How can I achieve this goal?

And how can I handle new users and old surveys? So, if I'm a new user, I should answer to all older surveys, but how can I do it? What kind of relationships do I have to design?

Comment: You are still unclear. Where's the problem? Users write to a table, admin writes to a table.. what's not working?

Comment: Have you considered having **one** table for all surveys, instead of creating a new each time?

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to dynamically create a new DB table; that implies that there is some structure in the data that your PHP code knows about, but isn't actually stored in your DB.

You need to think about the entities in the system; at its simplest, I can think of 3:

- a survey, with its name, when it was created, etc
- a survey question, associated to a particular survey, but there could be any number for a survey
- a survey answer, associated to a survey question, and the member who answered it

Your current model only really accounts for the last of these, and does so using numbered columns, which is a sure sign you should be thinking about normalisation.

If you create 3 tables, one for each of those entities, the relationships you need should become clearer:

- A survey could have a minimum age as a column, or be associated to a set of rows in another table to describe how to select members to ask.
- The surveys a member has answered is easy to query from the answers table, or perhaps a table which relates members to surveys, and lists when they answered.
- From those two, you can find all the surveys a particular member should answer, and exclude the ones they already have answered.